# Одинаковый размер столбиков в MPAndroidChart при изменении маштаба

Tags: android, диаграммы

Использую библиотеку MpAndroidChart для построения графиков. Мне нужно, чтобы ширина столбиков оставалась статична, относительно экрана устройства. В BarChart ширина столбика устанавливается относительно размера всего графика, и при скейле, ширина столбика тоже изменяется, мне же нужно чтобы они были статичны, например 8 dp.

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать отключить масштабирование по горизонтали
`chart.setScaleXEnabled(false)`

Comment: Спасибо, не вариант. Во первых это я уже сделал по вертикали, а во вторых нужно чтобы оно маштабировалось.

Comment: Но ведь масштабирование по горизонтали это и есть изменение ширины столбцов и расстояния между ними... Вообще мельком код посмотрел - с ходу не увидел вариантов как то управлять шириной столбцов. Как вариант - наследоваться и вносить правки в отрисовку самому. Хотя может кто более знающий подойдет.

Comment: Есть, можно установить ширину столбца, изначально она установлена 0.85f, как вариант, можнослеживать маштабирование, получать коофициент масштаба пересчитывать и устанавливать, но это мало того что похоже на глобальный костыль, так ещё при уменьшении масштаба к стартовому значению, он может перепрыгнуть 1 и вернуть например 0,96 или вообще 0,52, от чего после нескольких манипуляций столбцы становятся невидимыми.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = new BarData( dataset);     
data.setBarWidth(0.4f);
```

0.4f - это ширина столбца

Comment: Спасибо конечно, но вы пробовали увеличивать график?